# Including scss in react-native project?

Tags: react-native

Is there a way to work with scss files in react native application? I am just curious and don't have much knowledge in react-native application architecture, But was thinking of using my current project scss files to work with the new react-native-android project we are planning to build.

**REACT NATIVE VERSION : "0.46.4"**

**REACT VERSION : "16.0.0-alpha.12"**

**BABEL-PRESET-REACT-NATIVE: "2.1.0"**

**UPDATE :**

I searched a little found out [css-to-react-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-to-react-native) which kinda let me transform my css into react-native stylesheet object, kinda **workaround** for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Yes, you can.

https://github.com/kristerkari/react-native-sass-transformer

It takes scss like:

```
.myClass {
  color: blue;
}
.myOtherClass {
  color: red;
}
```

and converts it to

```
var styles = {
  myClass: {
    color: "blue"
  },
  myOtherClass: {
    color: "red"
  }
};
```

Easy peasy.

Comment: Unfortunately, this package is barely maintained. Maybe it works, but don't expect much improvements on the course.

Comment: Tried with expo v45.0.0 and react-native v0.68.2 but it's not working. Needs to be maintained.

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR**: No you cannot.

In react-native we are using inline style, which you can attain using `Stylesheet.create`.

Why you cannot *CSS like* styling is, In react native there are no `#id` either `.class`, so you cannot apply the style into `#id` or `.class` like you usually do in css styling. And also there is no related style, like in css you can do `.element1 > .element2`.

I think most developer main reason to use scss are to use nested class definition. Such as below:

```
.element1 {
  > .element2 {
    ...
  }
}
```

And because no *class like* feature in react-native component, there such method could not be apply in react-native.

Example how to create style in:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  bigblue: {
    color: 'blue',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 30,
  },
  red: {
    color: 'red',
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. was able to research and find something as a workaround.

Comment: Vipul : Can you tell us the workaround? We are caught up in a similar situation.

Comment: @NG. I wrote the code to first convert my SCSS file into CSS using node-sass and then into JSON file and lastly importing the same as JSON object in my files and converted the JSON object as CSS object using [https://github.com/aramk/CSSJSON] CSS-JSON converter.And lastly used CSS-TO-REACT-NATIVE as a converter for CSS to stylesheet object.